# Angular2 routing with back button

Tags: routes, angular, back-button

Bellow is the structure

```ts
app.component
/posts/posts.component
/shared/shared.component
/shared/gallery.component
```

under app.component, I have

```ts
@RouteConfig([
    { path: './shared/...', name: 'Shared', component: SharedComponent },
    { path: './posts/...', name: 'Posts', component: PostsComponent}
])
```

under posts.component, I have

```ts
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/', name: 'PostList', component: PostListComponent, useAsDefault: true },
{ path: '/:id', name: 'PostDetail', component: PostDetailComponent },
{ path: '/:id/gallery', name: 'Gallery', component: GalleryComponent }
```

])

under gallery.component, I have

```ts
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';

import {Photo} from './photo';
import {GalleryService} from './gallery.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-gallery',
    template: `
<my-photo *ngFor="#item of items" [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + item.thumb + ')'"></my-photo>
    `
})

export class GalleryComponent {
    @Input() items;

    constructor(private _galleryService: GalleryService) {
        if (this._galleryService.get()) {
            this.items = this._galleryService.get(); 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can navigate to the gallery (from `http://server/posts/123` to  `http://server/posts/123/gallery`) okay, but when I click the browser back button, even though the url changes back, nothing in the viewport changes, my-gallery is not removed and my-post is not loaded.

If I switch to `HashLocationStrategy`, the back button works, but I would rather not change to that, yet.

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser console?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in plunkr?

Comment: Same issue here. Trying to find a solution. If I run across something, I'll post it here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Safari Back Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617698/angular2-safari-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the browser that you are using but this is a typical issue on Safari where it loads a persisted / cached version of the page but doesn't instantiate the javascript in the same way as other browsers.

I can't speak for the new rc1 router as I haven't tested it, but you can solve this issue with the old `router-deprecated` version using the following in you main application component. This is more of a work around and not intended to be used long term as this issue is surely something that will be fixed in ng2 nearing its proper release.

```
constructor(_router:Router, 
            _applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {
    _router.subscribe((uri)=> {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0) {
            // We appear to be using Safari...
            _applicationRef.zone.run(() => _applicationRef.tick());
        }
    });
}
```

The issue with this code is that it fires on every state change meaning that we're likely forcing the browser to do more than it has to but as I said, think of it as a short term fix.