# Angular2 Safari Back Button

Tags: safari, angular, angular2-routing

In the actual Angular2 beta 14 (and before) there seems to be an issue with the back button (when using routing, and several views) on Safari (actually using 9.1): https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7722

I also experienced this problem, while this works fine e.g. on Chrome.

I'm looking for a workaround until the issue is fixed?

Answer (score 5):

On "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.14"

I had to run the tick inside a zone to get it to work for me.

```ts
import {ApplicationRef, <anything else you need>} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router,<anything else you need>} from 'angular2/router';

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _ref: ApplicationRef, private _router: Router) {
        _router.subscribe((value) => {
            _ref.zone.run(() => _ref.tick());
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is partial workaround for this bug:

1. Inject `Router` and `ApplicationRef` into Application component
2. Subscribe for router changes and trigger full component tree check:

```ts
    router.subscribe((value)=>
    {
        //todo: check browser UA or any other parameters to detect back button, i.e. if (safari) {}

        //trigger change that will invoke init methods
        appRef.tick();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

#### angular2 - 2.15.8

```
constructor(private _ref: ApplicationRef, private _router: Router) {
        _router.events.subscribe((value) => {
            _ref.zone.run(() => _ref.tick());
        });
    }
```

Using `_router.subscribe` is deprecated and will throw **Undefined function** .subscribe() on _router.

Comment: have you tried `_router.params.subscribe(params => { ...  });`